# Inline-block element height and scrollable content box behaves in angular app different than in html-page

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tags

I am just facing a super weird problem. My actual goal was to build a scrollable flex-box content box between two sidebars (left and right) for an angular app. First I did a prototype in an html and it works fine! But then I started to implement it inside the app and the elements don't behave the same. In order to debug the problem, I replaced the elements and styles with exact the same tags and css styles, from my html-file, but it still doesn't look the same.

[How it looks with the html-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYGrs.png)

1. The sidebars have a full height
2. The centered content box has a vertical and horizontal scroll section.

[This is the outcome of the angular app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ALVD.png)

1. The height of the sidebars don't stretch over the full height.
2. the centered box has ONLY a horizontal scroll section.
3. The padding of the container seems to have an effect of the .boxsidebar, because the .boxsidebar is not sticking on top (like in image 1).

Here is the code, which is used for both solutions. In the angular app, the html is added in the app.component.html and the style in app.style.scss:

```html
<head>
  <style>
    body{
      margin: 0;
    }
    .boxsidebar{
      display: inline-block;
      width: 25%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: blue;
    }

    .container{
      display: inline-block;
      width: 74%;
    }

    .map{
      display: inline-flex;
      -webkit-flex-flow: column;
      flex-flow: column;
      height: 100%;
      width: 74%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 16px;
    }

    .toolbar{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: chartreuse;
    }

    .sidebar{
      display: inline-block;
      width: 25%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: blueviolet;
    }

    .wrapwrap{
      min-height: 0;
      flex: 1;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    .someBigStuff{
      background-color: aquamarine;
      height: 2000px;
      width: 2000px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<div class="box">
  <div class="boxsidebar">
    <h3>Hello</h3>
    <div class="sidebar_content">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="map">
      <div class="toolbar">Hello</div>
      <div class="wrapwrap">
        <div class="someBigStuff"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <h3>Hello</h3>
      <div class="sidebar_content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Final hint: I unchecked every additional style in the css-inspector window, so that both pages have the same base.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: A height in percent, requires the parent element to have an explicit height as well. (Or an implicit one, f.e. based on that the element is absolutely positioned with top and bottom.) As you can see with your snippet here, that does not behave like you said your HTML page would either - you would need to set 100% height for `.box`, `body` and `html` as well here. Angular wraps the whole thing in additional container elements AFAIK, so you would have to give those a height as well then.

Comment: Look into the `vh` unit, using `height: 100vh` is usually much easier in most such situations, and does not require the parent elements to have an explicit height.

Comment: Thank you so much, the height: 100vh fixes the problem, also makes the content box scrolling! Jipiiieh :)